# C identifier and main

Tags: c

1.Why **"main"** in the C main() function **identifier**? 
2.If main is an identifier then how does a program execution starts from **main** only.

Comment: I'm sorry, what?

Comment: What do mean by saying identifiers? Keywords? `main` is no keyword,

Comment: *"As we know that compiler have no any idea about the identifier"* I think you might be mixing this something else. Compiler (or the other parts of the toolchain) do know that the identifier `main` has a special meaning.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: “Identifier” is defined in C 2011 [N1570] 6.4.2: “An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore _, the lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates one or more entities as described in 6.2.1.”

Answer (score 3):

`main` is a function, almost exactly like any other.  It's named by an identifier, it gets called, it receives some arguments, it does something, it returns a value.  That's pretty much the definition of a function.  The designers of C were going for simplicity, so it made perfect sense to have the program's entry point be an ordinary function.

If you're an assembly language programmer, you may know that a program's entry point is simply an address, not a full-fledged function.  But that's assembly language talk: C is a higher-level language.

As others have explained, there's some low-level startup code somewhere (typically written in assembler), that has a program's *actual* entry point, as jumped to when your program starts up.  That startup code is the code that actually calls your `main` function.

I said that `main` is an ordinary function, and it mostly is, but it has three special properties not shared by other functions:

1. It's just about the only function that you ever write where you don't get to pick your own name, return value, and argument types -- those are all chosen for you (or, if you want to think of it that way, forced on you) by the language.  For example, the return type just *has* to be `int`, because the language says so.  You don't get to make it some other type just because you want to (although of course lots and lots of programmers make it `void`, and often get away with it).
2. `main` actually has two valid sets of arguments it can accept: either zero or two, namely `int` and `char **` (traditionally named `argc` and `argv`).
3. As a *very* special exception, even through `main` returns `int`, you're allowed to not have a `return` statement, and the compiler will basically insert one for you, making `main()` return 0 by default.

Answer (score 0):

C standard defines the `main` function as the program entry point. It is called from the startup code or the program loader.

BTW you can change it (I do not know why but if you want you can) - example for the baremetal ARM

startup:

```
/* Call the clock system intitialization function.*/
    bl  SystemInit
/* Call static constructors */
    bl __libc_init_array
/* Call the application's entry point.*/
    bl  initCCMRAM
/* Here was the main call */
    bl  my_entry_point_function 

LoopForever:
    b LoopForever
```

and in the C code

```
int my_entry_point_function(void)
{
...
}
```